# Switches after finishing Splinter Group

Tags: borderlands-2

Just after you finish the necessary killing for the quest Splinter Group, in the Bloodshot Stronghold, there are four switches (wall, tv, pipe valve, floor lever), which change five lights .... but I haven't managed to find the right pattern.

Is this a red herring, or is there some reward if I can get them all to green?

Comment: I got this after messing with switches for 5 minutes. Our group almost gave up. Good to see there's a proven solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is actually an Easter Egg in this area if you manage to get all five lights green. Apparently, the switches all start in random positions for each player so there is not one unique solution immediately available to you, although you can deduce the solution based on what light(s) each switch triggers:

- Lever – 1 & 3 or 4 & 5
- Switch on Wall – 5 or 2 & 3 & 5
- TV – 1 or 1 & 3 & 4
- Wheel – 1 & 3 & 5 or 1 & 2

For more details, [here is the source](https://web.archive.org/web/20121104063354/http://www.omfgnetwork.com:80/2012/how-to-solve-the-light-puzzle-in-bloodshot-stronghold/).

In any case, if you are successful, the Splinter Group's leader "**[Flinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSnt6.jpg)**" will crawl out of a drain and fight you.

[image]

Comment: Anecdotal, but I killed Flinter last night, he dropped 73 bucks and a white rocket launcher.

Comment: He always drops random loot - incorrect information was edited into the answer.

Comment: Strangely enough, I didn't realize it was a puzzle (never noticed the lights) and Flinter jumped out while I was fiddling with a switch.

Comment: The lights are randomly lit? No wonder I had to do the same combo multiple times...

Comment: @KBKarma The lights should be all red when you start, it's just that you don't know what state each switch starts in.

Answer (score 9):

If you get them all red go to the valve/wheel. Turn once.  Then tv two times. Then wall mount three times.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little video that could help you.